# Converting a function to a power series with only variables. A bit stuck

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to convert this function into a power series and I'm a tad stuck on where to go from here:

$$f(x) = \frac{x+a}{x^2 + a^2}$$ and a $\gt 0$

Are these steps valid:

$$(x+a) \cdot \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2}$$

$$ = \frac{(x+a)}{a^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{x}{a})^2}$$

$$ = \frac{(x+a)}{a^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{-x}{a})^2}$$

$$ = \frac{(x+a)}{a^2} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big(\frac{-x}{a}\big)^n$$

$$ = \frac{(x+a)}{a^2} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \big(\frac{x}{a}\big)^n$$

But I'm stuck on how to incorporate the fraction on the outside back in.

Comment: $\left(\frac{x}a\right)^2\ne-\left(-\frac{x}a\right)^2$ and where did the power of $2$ go in the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from before a mistake was made,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x+a}{a^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^2}{a^2}}
&=\frac{x+a}{a^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1  -\left(-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{x+a}{a^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{x+a}{a^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{a^{2k}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x+a)\left((-1)^kx^{2k}\right)}{a^{2k+2}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{a^{2k+2}}+\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{a^{2k+1}}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor}}{a^{k+1}}x^k\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) Nice answer!

Comment: Probably the $n$ in the final sum should be replaced by $k$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes, thanks!

Comment: How did you get from the second to last step to the last step? I don't see it... @PeterForeman

Comment: In each pair of terms we can see that the power of $x$ is $k$ and the power of $a$ is $k+1$ but every pair of terms has the same sign hence the floor function. This function just supplies the correct sequence of signs - $++--++\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}\frac1a-\frac{x^2}{a^3}+\frac{x^4}{a^5}-\frac{x^6}{a^7}+\cdots&=\frac1a\left(1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2+\left(\frac xa\right)^4-\left(\frac xa\right)^6+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac1a\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\\&=\frac a{x^2+a^2}\end{align}if $\left\lvert\frac xa\right\rvert<1$. A similar computation shows that$$\frac x{a^2}-\frac{x^3}{a^4}+\frac{x^5}{a^6}-\frac{x^7}{a^8}+\cdots=\frac x{x^2+a^2},$$again, if $\left\lvert\frac xa\right\rvert<1$. Therefore,$$\left\lvert\frac xa\right\rvert<1\implies\frac{x+a}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a+\frac x{a^2}-\frac x{a^3}-\frac{x^3}{a^4}+\cdots$$

Comment: (+1) I did it the algebraic way.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the fraction as 
$$f(x) = \frac{x+a}{x^2 + a^2}=\frac 1a \frac{1+\cfrac xa}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{a^2}}$$
and set $t=\dfrac xa$. You have to find the expansion of
\begin{align}
\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}&=(1+t)\,\frac 1{1+t^2}\\
&=(1+t)(1-t^2+t^4-t^6+t^8-\dotsm)\\
&=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+t^8+\dots\\
&\quad\, +t-t^3+t^5-t^7+t^9-\dotsm \\
&=(1+t)-(t^2+t^3)+(t^4+t^5)-(t^6+t^7)+\dotsm
\end{align}
Can you find a general formula from these elements?